# Why setInterval runs slower than expected?

Tags: node.js

I expect in following code `setInterval` runs 100 times before `setTimeout`.

```
var current = 0;

var timer = setInterval(function(){
    process.stdout.write(current.toString() + '\n');

    if(current === 1000) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        process.stdout.write('Done');   
    }

    current += 10;
}, 10);

setTimeout(function(){
    process.stdout.write('This is 1000.\n');
}, 1000);
```

But its the result:

```
860
870
880
This is 1000.
890
900
910
920
930
940
950
960
970
980
990
1000
Done
```

What I did not understand about `setInterval`? I think last `setInterval` and `setTimeout` should run together at the end.

Comment: setInterval probably does its best to execute on the time you set, but since you run code in the interval it isn't guaranteed that it will execute and run exactly every 10ms as it will also take some small amount of time to run your code. JS isn't a real-time language. You can expect some diff in script execution time depending on HW/browser and current load on you machine as well

Comment: All the answers and the duplicated questions are not answer this question! The queue of nodejs should be far more fast than 10ms, and nodejs never says it will up round the interval to 10ms (which the browsers clearly state to be 4ms or something IIRC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All scheduled code is put in a single queue and processed by one thread. If the `setInterval` function can't finish faster than 10ms, the execution time will fall behind the schedule. The precise time of execution cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

`setInveral` and `setTimeout` have no execution/scheduling guarantees and going down to as much as 10ms intervals will almost always fail. The best you can probably get for a predictable interval on browsers is [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). That will usually match the refresh rate of the screen, so usually 16.66ms intervals for 60Hz. Keep in mind that this can still drop frames and it may get suspended if the tab is not in focus.

Comment: There is no such thing link `requestAnimationFrame` in `node.js`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the `process.stdout.write` which is a consumming I/O operation takes more than `10ms`.

`setInterval()` is waiting the function to finish before to start an other one.